# Can't add classes using jQuery from a JSON string with get_body_class()

Tags: jquery, ajax, array, json, customization

In order to refresh the classes on the `<body>`element after an AJAX call, I am writing at the top of my AJAX response the following in JSON: `$o[ 'classes' ] = get_body_class('project');`

I can then see in the JSON response the following:

`"classes":["single","single-project"
,"postid-1793","logged-in","project","default"]`

What I am trying to do is to put all those classes into the body using jQuery in order to "refresh" them and transfer the informations regarding the classes of the current template loaded in AJAX.

```
var thecontent_classes = data.classes;
//alert(thecontent_classes);
$('body').removeClass();
$('body').addClass(thecontent_classes);
```

With the previous code, it is unfortunately not working because it is adding the JSON list with all the classes separated by comas if I'm testing the content of the variable with an alert. I tried to replace the comas by spaces using str.replace without success... Maybe there is an easier way, either with the PHP side or with the str replace ??

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`get_body_class()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_body_class) is going to [return an `array` of classes](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L721), which is then (per code not published in your question) JSON encoded into that comma separated string. While you can manipulate that in JavaScript, the easiest thing to do is [`implode`](http://php.net/IMPLODE) the string before encoding:

```
$c = get_body_class('project');
$c = implode($c,' ');
```

You should have a nice neat space separated string that you don't have to manipulate further.

Comment: Working great at the top of my few ajax specific templates with `$myNewClasses = get_body_class('project');
$myNewClasses = implode($myNewClasses, ' ');
$o[ 'classes' ] = $myNewClasses;`

I didn't know about this `implode()` function. Thank you for the help and fast answer !

Comment: `implode()` is Core PHP. It is worth browsing the PHP docs once in awhile ;)